# onRequestPermissionsResult not being called in fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a fragment in which I have recyclerview and setting data in this recyclerview using recyclerview adapter.

Now, I am having a button in adapter's list item clicking on which I need to check the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in android for new permission model in android.

I have created a new function in this adapter's fragment to check if permission is granted or not and request for permission if not granted already.

I have passed MyFragment.this as a paramter in adapter and calling the fragment's method on the button click in adapter.

I have used the below code to call requestPermission in fragment.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
       requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                ConstantVariables.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
```

I have overridden the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method in fragment by using the below code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ConstantVariables.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, proceed to the normal flow.
                startImageUploading();
            } else {}
```

But it is not getting called, instead of this Activity's onRequestPermissionsResult method is getting called.

Am I doing something wrong here, please help me if anyone have idea here.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189121

You need to use android support library 23.3.+.
After that do not forget to add

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

on the activity (`if super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults`) not called in the activity, fragment will not receive onRequestPermissionsResult)